# PyTorch C++ extension: How to index tensor and update it?

Tags: python, c++, pytorch

I'm creating a PyTorch C++ extension and after much research I can't figure out how to index a tensor and update its values. I found out how to iterate over a tensor's entries using the `data_ptr()` method, but that's not applicable to my use case.

Given is a matrix `M`, a list of lists (blocks) of index pairs `P` and a function `f: dtype(M)^2 -> dtype(M)^2` that takes two values and spits out two new values.

I'm trying to implement the following pseudo code:

```
for each block B in P:
    for each row R in M:
        for each index-pair (i,j) in B:
            M[R,i], M[R,j] = f(M[R,i], M[R,j])
```

After all, this code is going to run on the GPU using CUDA, but since I don't have any experience with that, I wanted to first write a pure C++ program and then convert it.

Can anyone suggest how to do this or how to convert the algorithm to do something equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted to do can be done using the
`tensor.accessor<scalar_dtype, num_dimensions>()`
method. If executing on the GPU instead use `scalars.packed_accessor64<scalar_dtype, num_dimensions, torch::RestrictPtrTraits>()`
or
`scalars.packed_accessor32<scalar_dtype, num_dimensions, torch::RestrictPtrTraits>()` (depending on the size of your tensor).

```
auto num_rows = scalars.size(0);
matrix = torch::rand({10, 8});
auto a = matrix.accessor<float, 2>();
for (auto i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
    auto x = a[i][some_index];
    auto new_x = some_function(x);
    a[i][some_index] = new_x;
}
```